# NumberFormatException For Input String "4018.B"

Tags: java, android, matcher

The following code comes from a Android App for Handheld Scanner Device; the Device should scan different Barcodes and QR codes, different digit ranges, numbers and digits;

that´s why I decided to go with .matcher instead of Regular Expressions; The following code works fine when it comes to parse combinations like "1367+700" etc.:

```
editBarcode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //tv is the TextView.
            public void onClick(View v) {
                code = editBarcode.getText().toString();
                XXXStorageApp.getInstance().setScannedCode(code);
                editBarcode.setText("");
              if (ScanService.checkEnteredCode(code, basic, content, MainDetailActivity.this) == true) {
                    return;
                }
                else {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(code);
                  Matcher matcher = p.matcher(Pattern.quote("\\+"));
                    if (matcher.find()){
                       retrievedItemNo = String.valueOf(matcher);
                    }
                String intermediateItemNo = code;
                String[] splitString = intermediateItemNo.split(Pattern.quote("+"));
                retrievedItemNo = splitString [0];
                String intermediateString = code.substring(code.indexOf("+") + 1);
                retrievedQuantity = intermediateString.split("\\+")[0];
                if(XXXStorageApp.getInstance().NoList.contains(retrievedItemNo) || XXXStorageApp.getInstance().EanList.contains(scannedCode)){
                    Log.d(String.valueOf(XXXStorageApp.getInstance().NoList),"NoList");
                    Log.d(String.valueOf(XXXStorageApp.getInstance().EanList),"EanList");
                }
                else {
                    Log.d(String.valueOf(XXXStorageApp.getInstance().NoList),"NoList");
                    Log.d(String.valueOf(XXXStorageApp.getInstance().EanList),"EanList");
                    Vibrator vibrator;
                    vibrator = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    vibrator.vibrate(3000);
                    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                    r.play();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.not_in_database, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (!addBooking.isEnabled() == true && removeBooking.isEnabled())

                {
                    AddBookingMessage message = new AddBookingMessage();
                    message.setType("add-item-to-pallet");
                    message.setPalNo(receivedPalNo);
                    message.setItem(retrievedItemNo);
                    if (String.valueOf(retrievedQuantity).matches("") ||
                            retrievedQuantity == null ||
                            retrievedQuantity.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainDetailActivity.this, 0);
                        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                        dialog.setCancelable(true);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.sortiment_layout);
                        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                        TextView textView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                        Button okButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
                        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                retrievedQuantity = textView.getText().toString();
                                message.setQuantity(Integer.valueOf(retrievedQuantity));
                                message.setSource(source);
                                message.setTime(time);
                                RestClient.putBookingOnPallet(basic, message, MainDetailActivity.this);
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        Button cancelButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
                        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                else
                    {
                        message.setQuantity(Integer.valueOf(retrievedQuantity));
                        message.setSource(source);
                        message.setTime(time);
                        RestClient.putBookingOnPallet(basic, message, MainDetailActivity.this);
                    }

                }

                if (addBooking.isEnabled() && !removeBooking.isEnabled() == true)
                {
                    AddBookingMessage message = new AddBookingMessage();
                    message.setType("remove-item-from-pallet");
                    message.setPalNo(receivedPalNo);
                    message.setItem(retrievedItemNo);
                    message.setEan(scannedCode);
                    if (spinner != null && spinner.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                        source = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    }
                    if (String.valueOf(retrievedQuantity).matches("") || retrievedQuantity == null
                            || retrievedQuantity.trim().isEmpty())
                    {
                            final Dialog enterDialog = new Dialog(MainDetailActivity.this, 0);
                            enterDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                            enterDialog.setCancelable(true);
                            enterDialog.setContentView(R.layout.sortiment_layout);
                            enterDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                            TextView enterQuantityView = enterDialog.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                            Button okQuantityButton = enterDialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
                            okQuantityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    retrievedQuantity = enterQuantityView.getText().toString();
                                    message.setQuantity(Integer.valueOf(retrievedQuantity));
                                    message.setSource(source);
                                    message.setTime(time);
                                    RestClient.removeItemFromPallet(basic, message, MainDetailActivity.this);
                                    enterDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            Button cancelQuantityButton = enterDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
                            cancelQuantityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    enterDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            enterDialog.show();
                        }
                        else {
                            message.setQuantity(Integer.valueOf(retrievedQuantity));
                            message.setSource(source);
                            message.setTime(time);
                            RestClient.removeItemFromPallet(basic, message, MainDetailActivity.this);
                    }
                }
                editBarcode.setText("");
            }}
```

however the App crashes with a

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4018.B"
```

So, the problem here is to parse a string like "4018.B+95".

I don´t know how to handle this mixed input String with .matcher and definitely don´t want to use a Regular Expression; so basically, all of the following Input Strings - including Type conversion - should be handled correctly:

```
1256+70

1235.B+70

1256+70+DB

1235.B+70+DB

1256+70+DB2020-123

1235.B+70+DB2020-123

1256+0+DB2020-123

1235.B+0+DB2020-123
```

So, basically I need a condition for .matcher() that handles input like

"1235.B"

a mixed Integer and String; I need to store it in one variable which is of type String;
the problem here is that the "." in "1235.B" is not recognized and the App crashes hence, because the Number contains a string (".B")

So, two questions here:

1. How can I use .matcher() to recognize if a String contains ".B" or ".C" or anything similar?
2. How do I handle the different Types correctly in one Variable type?

As I am stuck with this, I would appreciate any hints or help.

Comment: what are these ".B",".C","DB" "+","-" what these value signifies in here ?

Comment: You know that the classes `Pattern` and `Matcher` **are** using regular expressions. I mean there's probably nothing wrong with using them here, but you're so insistent on not using regex, that I thought you should know.

Comment: @dinkar_kumar: the strings before the "+" and after the "+" should be separated and stored in variables

Comment: @JoachimSauer: right, maybe I put this a bit wrong; I ment not to use if (String matches RegEx) then {execute code}, but use .matcher(expression) to {execute code}. Do you have anymore hints or help on that?